# About "ls" , how can I just show directories only (except linked directories and hidden directories)

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I meet some problem about "ls" this command

I want to print just only directory without hidden or linked

but I use man ls to look the explanation , but I didn't found

if there is a flag that I can do what I want ...

thanks

below is the question I am going to solve ...

4. Display the visible exits

```
This is two commands: The first command prints "Visible exits: "
-> It must not advance the cursor to the next line.
The second command displays the visible exits and then a period (.).
-> To prevent the linked directories contents from also displaying, you 
will need a flag.
-> Several wildcard patterns will be needed.
-> The period will be the last of these patterns.
   The period means the current directory. But here it will seem, to
   the user, to be a period at the end of a sentence listing visible
   exits.
-> You will need to use a flag to keep the output from being
   sorted (otherwise the period will not stay at the end).
-> With several patterns to search, some may have no matches. That
   is OK, but we don't want to see warning messages. Redirect these.
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me. You'll need to give us a demonstration inside your question.

Comment: like I had 3 directory now "a" "ab" "c" but c is a link directory

I want to use a command to print just a , ab

Answer (score 21):

Use `ls -d */`. The `*/` is a wildcard that expands to all directories in current directory (directories end in `/`). `-d` tells `ls` to list the names of directories given as arguments and not their content.

Comment: If all the OP needs is the name then `ls` serves no purpose here and `echo` would work just as well.

Comment: Given the wording in the question this may also not be enough (no hidden directories). That being said the `sorted` bit of the question confuses me as does the bit about the `.` at the end and the current directory.

Comment: but using ls -d */. print the link directory as usual QQ , I don't want to print the link directory

Answer (score 3):

You should look into the [`stat`](http://man.cx/stat) command. Something like:

```
stat -c '%F %n' * | sed -n '/^directory /s///p'
```

There's also [`find`](http://man.cx/find)

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print
```

Find will show you hidden directories (including `.` the current directory)