# Using ls in Linux to show directories only

Tags: linux, ls, manual

I'm getting myself familiar with Linux (Debian 9). However I managed to get myself confused with the `ls` command manual. I made up the following trivial setting for testing:

```
meouser:~/triv_dir$ ls -laR
.:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  4 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:55 a
drwxr-xr-x  2 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:42 b
-rw-r--r--  1 meouser meouser    6 Mar 27 15:44 c
-rw-r--r--  1 meouser meouser    6 Mar 27 15:44 d

./a:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 4 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:42 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 meouser meouser    4 Mar 27 15:50 aa
-rw-r--r-- 1 meouser meouser    4 Mar 27 15:50 ab
drwxr-xr-x 2 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:55 a_sub_1
drwxr-xr-x 2 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:55 a_sub_2

./a/a_sub_1:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:55 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 meouser meouser    4 Mar 27 15:55 aaa

./a/a_sub_2:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:55 ..

./b:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:42 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 meouser meouser    4 Mar 27 15:50 ba
-rw-r--r-- 1 meouser meouser    4 Mar 27 15:50 bb
```

I would like to see all the directory names and their subdirectories, but not the filenames. That is, I want something like `ls --insert-options-here` so that the output is this subset from above:

```
.:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  4 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:41 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:55 a
drwxr-xr-x  2 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:42 b

./a:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 4 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:42 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:55 a_sub_1
drwxr-xr-x 2 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:55 a_sub_2
```

According to `ls` manual that should be achieved by `ls -ldR`.

```
meouser:~/triv_dir$ man ls

   -a, --all
          do not ignore entries starting with .

   -d, --directory
          list directories themselves, not their contents

   -l     use a long listing format

   -R, --recursive
          list subdirectories recursively
```

But this is what happens instead: only the `'.'` is shown.

```
meouser:~/triv_dir$ ls -ldR
drwxr-xr-x 4 meouser meouser 4096 Mar 27 15:42 .
```

What am I missing from the manual?

I noticed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29277454/11199684 that this can be achieved by
`find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -print`
which is impressive but it gives less information than the ls output above. Besides, I might not know beforehand the correct maxdepth? And above all, for future needs I'm actually interested in teaching myself from the manuals. Advice are appreciated.

Comment: If you use `zsh`, you can do `ls -ld **/*(/)` Not sure if possible with plain `ls`

Comment: @balki I seem to have `bash`. That gives error message `bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`(' `. `zsh` is unrecognized command.

Comment: Yes, it does not work in bash. If possible, install zsh (`sudo apt install zsh`). it is a better shell than bash and mostly backwards compatible with bash.

Answer (score 3):

The `-d` option apply to `[FILE]` given as input, in your case, as none are given, you fall back to the default one : the current directory. The recursivity doesn't apply as no directory are returned.

To get the same output as `ls` with the `find` command, you can combine them :

```
find . -type d -exec ls -ld {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution, it is an interesting one and will take me some time to digest that syntax.  But I don't quite get your first paragraph.  With `ls -ldR .` there is input (the current directory) but I still get the same result as with `ls -ldR` (only `.`).  And with `ls -ldR *` I get the same result as with `ls -l` (list of a,b,c,d).

Comment: I tried to explain why the manual says "list directories themselves". Another way to say it is "list directories themselves given as input". You can think of the `-d` option having the precedence over the `-R` one (if you don't list the content, how can the recursivity works ?).

Comment: @jww Do you mean that this question is more appropriate on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

in some way you could use the `grep` tool to filter the results:

```
ll -A | grep ^d
```

if you want to use it programatically, in a bash script you can have only the dir names (but `find` might be better for that):

```
ll -A | grep / | awk '{print $9}'
```